# extracting extra records from mysql tables when there are no primary keys

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find all the records that are in t1 but not in t2. I know there are more records in t1 than in t2 because when I run

```
select count(*) 
from t1;

select count(*) 
from t2;
```

I get 21,500 records and 21,000 records respectively. But the problem is these tables are not normalized, there are no primary keys, therefore I cannot do something like this:

```
 SELECT id FROM t1 
    where t1.id
    not in (
    SELECT t2.id
    FROM t2 
    where t2.id is not null);
```

or this

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.id 
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2
ON t1.id = t2.id 
where t2.id is null
```

as both return null, as the id numbers match perfectly, there seems to be the same exact amount of ids. There must be another field which is not matching.

**UPDATE**

I ended up doing this:

```
select id, count(id) 
from t1 
group by id; 
select id, count(id) 
from t2 
group by id
```

it gave the same amount of claim numbers and the count of times it shows up. I copied and pasted it into excel and just subtracted one count from the other and did a conditional formatting to only show the ones that are not zero and this gave me all the ids that showed up in one table more than the other. (Sloppy solution, but it was able to resolve the issue).

Comment: These tables are not tables.

Comment: @Strawberry how come ?

Comment: In RDBMs, a PK is a prerequisite of a table definition.

Comment: But they are tables @Strawberry, well if table = rectangular array of cells... :)

Comment: Have you checked for rows where the id is null?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson yup :-/

Comment: Pity that would have explained it. What type is id?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson varchar

Comment: And is it the same (or at least a 1-1 mapping) between them.

Comment: Varchar.. leading or trailing spaces, differing collations are two possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.  A bad database design and somehow bogus data is being inserted into your tables.

I don't know if this will work without indexes.

A **left outer join** should get you started (look up the syntax).

You should end up with something like:

```
t1.id   t2.id
1        1
2        2
3        null
4        4
```

Comment: Actually, you probably need a FULL OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix the tables by adding a primary key on 'id' to both tables using MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 ADD PRIMARY KEY (id)
ALTER TABLE t2 ADD PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

Comment: its going to complain about the duplicates, and although there are duplicate id's there are stuff that pertain to the id that are not duplicate. I would have to go normalize their whole database..

Comment: removed the reference to Steve.